# What does this street sign showing Japantown represent?

Tags: japan, driving, california, san-jose-california

While driving in San Jose downtown in California, I saw the following street sign:

[image]

What does this street sign showing Japantown represent? I understand that it is pointing to the nearby Japantown but I don't understand the symbol.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's simply the logo of Japantown, which is the stylized flower of a  [Japanese plum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prunus_mume) (ume).

> the logo of San Jose Japantown in present time is a plum blossom, because many of the farmers grew plums.

https://japantowncommunitycongress.wordpress.com/history/